# TinyMce Editor and jbimages Plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce, autoresize

I'm having issues with the jbimages plugin and the autoresize.  The autoresize plugin works great but when I insert an image using jbimages, it doesn't resize it.  Is there a way to manually call the autoresize? Maybe call the autoresize when something is entered?

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#newCommentText",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists charmap hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "media nonbreaking",
            "table contextmenu directionality paste jbimages autoresize"
        ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    width: 308,
    height: 35,
    content_css: "css/content.css",
    toolbar: "media jbimages", 
    statusbar: false,
    //init_instance_callback: function (inst) { inst.execCommand('mceAutoResize'); }
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you mean the auto-resize setting within jbimages? If not could you give a link to the autoresize plugin you are using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means the autoresize plugin which resizes the editor itself as content is being added. I just walked into the same problem that it doesn't resize when you add an image using the jbimages plugin. Actually sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't so I think it's a timing issue. I already tried adding an event handler for the 'change' event and firing the mceautoresize command, but that also doesn't work.